# ./txtdb: line 9: [: =: unary operator expected

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

```
echo "Choose from the following options"
echo "1- Display full Database"
echo "2 - exit program"
read usrChoice
if [ $usrChoice  -eq 1 ] ; then
        cat energydrink.txt
elif [ $userChoice -eq  2 ]
then
        echo "you chose the option 2"
else
        echo "Please choose a viable command"
fi
```

I do not understand why i keep getting this error. The script works if I input 1, but I get this error if I input 2

./txtdb: line 9: [: =: unary operator expected
Please choose a viable command

Comment: It should be `usrChoice -eq 2` not `userChoice.  -eq 2`.

Answer (score 2):

Quote your variables.

With un quoted and empty variable

```
[ $UserChoice -eq 1 ]
-bash: [: -eq: unary operator expected
```

With quotes but empty variables

```
[ "$UserChoice" -eq 1 ]
-bash: [: : integer expression expected
```